# Nginx vhost downloads file

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, php-fpm

I've setup nginx and php as [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) suggests. I've created a second vhost which is the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /projects/mydomain/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name  mydomain.gr;


    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

Php and nginx works fine if I visit mydomain.gr/index.php but when I visit mydomain.gr it will download a file with the content of the index.php and the name is download. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try_files rather than index:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /projects/mydomain/;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.php $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm =404;

    server_name  mydomain.gr;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

Comment: No it didn't work. It has the same behavior as before.

Comment: Strange but it seems like some chrome browser problem with cache. I tried it with incognito and it works.

Comment: Great, there is no reason why it wouldn't work. Always use direct `curl` requests for this kind of testing. Browsers add a ton of complexity that you cannot easily track.